# Propose to re-open a question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

[create an OHLC series from ticker data using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830472/create-an-ohlc-series-from-ticker-data-using-r) was closed as "too localised". I don't think it's any more localised than many other questions in the `R` tag.

Questions about `zoo`, `quantmod`, `xts` and so on are pretty common and this one fills a useful gap in the standard `R-SIG-Finance` question set. (That community overlaps a lot with SO's `R` community.)

I'd like to provide a thorough answer to it.

Comment: So I guess one thing you could do is edit out his answer. Kev, the asker, hasn't been online in a month, but his answer will still be in the revision history if he wanted to self-answer later on. This would still allow you to make sure the question is actually a question. Good luck! :)  Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not really sure if this question is ready to be reopened. The op didn't make any edits to it to improve it, and he posted his answer in the actual question body, which makes for very confusing Q&A.

The other issue is that the data that is included as part of this question exists on some third-party server, subject to be removed at any time either by the hosting provider, the op, or some other reason outside Stack Exchange's control. The best questions on Stack Overflow are self-contained so they'll be useful to future visitors. If that data were to disappear, I'd seriously question how useful the post would really be to future visitors.

I don't know enough about R to say whether it's too localized or not, but if nothing has changed to improve the post, then I don't personally see it being reopened, especially after almost 10 months of sitting there with no edits.

With that said, if you think you can edit it and fix it, that might be a good first step to convincing the community to reopen the question. Good luck! :)

Comment: In all fairness, the OP edited the answer into the question *because* it got closed.

Comment: Sure @NullUserExceptionอ_อ, but surely that's one of the problems that needs to be resolved, either by editing it out and giving the op a shoutout to dig in the revision history and add it later, or just removing it completely. If I wanted to get the question reopened, I'd start there. I'm not pointing out why it got closed so much as I am what needs to be done to convince people that it should be reopened. ;)  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I believe that your second paragraph explains the reasoning behind the closure: as soon as that data disappears, the question becomes much less useful to everyone else -> too localized. I don't know anything about R either, but the task itself seems like a generally-applicable problem.

Comment: Okay, so Animuson was kind enough to rollback to revision #1, and I added in the CVS data. It might be overkill, but I'll let someone who knows R determine if the data set can be reduced or if the entire thing is needed for context. But with the edits, I feel more confident that my reopen vote won't be needlessly wasted on a buried question, since this is not only cleaned up but bumped to the top of the Active tab. ;)  [Take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830472/create-an-ohlc-series-from-ticker-data-using-r).

Comment: CSV, not CVS ;)  typo...